# iOS framework/bundle with replaceable assets

Tags: ios, frameworks, bundle

I am trying to make an iOS framework with some basic UI-Controls. I want users to easily re-skin the theme of my controls therefore I am loading the assets, storyboards and xibb files from an asset bundle.

I am using image.xcassets for assets. The bundle generation changes it to assets.car

I want the assets to be easily replaceable within the bundle for users to re-skin. What is the proper way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Resources / images assets added the app bundle. So you cannot add anything in bundle framework at runtime ( user cannot change the skin from the bundle )

You can achieve by 2 ways

1. At launch, check whether the image files exist in the documents directory. If not, copy the bundle images to the document folder.
2. Check name of the images why loading from the bundle after check with local / documents folder get the same copy of the image and use that for new skin as of user wish .